# Slow sub-SELECT GROUP BY JPQL query

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jpql

The following JPQL takes about 1.5 seconds to execute against PG 9.6:

```
@Query(" SELECT t FROM T t WHERE t.id in ("
     + "   SELECT MAX(t.id) FROM T t, C c "
     + "     WHERE t.m           = :m     "
     + "       AND t.c           = c      "
     + "       AND c.createdDate < :date  "
     + "     GROUP BY t.m, t.p            "
     + "   )                              ")
List<T> tByDate(@Param("m") M m, @Param("date") LocalDateTime date);
```

Any ideas how to speed this up without changing the database model?

**Table T** (size 45k)

```
CREATE TABLE public.t 
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('t_id_seq'::regclass),
  c_id bigint NOT NULL,
  m_id bigint NOT NULL,
  p_id bigint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT t_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fkcdo362oanw5jshu29kavksyfy FOREIGN KEY (m_id)
    REFERENCES public.m (id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fkjpyqqd0vys4jayau98eij2xv3 FOREIGN KEY (c_id)
    REFERENCES public.c (id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fknjjuiq1kn44mu5299dn67t3np FOREIGN KEY (p_id)
    REFERENCES public.p (id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

**Table C** (size 45k)

```
CREATE TABLE public.c
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('c_id_seq'::regclass),
  created_by character varying(255),
  created_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  m_id bigint,
  CONSTRAINT c_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fkbv33l9w17owvi5kgctqvaepn0 FOREIGN KEY (m_id)
    REFERENCES public.m (id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

**Table M** (size 200)

```
CREATE TABLE public.m
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('m_id_seq'::regclass),
  created_by character varying(255),
  created_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  a_id bigint,
  CONSTRAINT m_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fkikqmae593j3mruwqy84pc56is FOREIGN KEY (a_id)
      REFERENCES public.a (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

**Table P** (size 5k)

```
CREATE TABLE public.p
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  created_by character varying(255),
  created_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  e character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  a_id bigint,
  CONSTRAINT p_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fkehggtafv310ewdtcq772pwl01 FOREIGN KEY (a_id)
      REFERENCES public.a (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Comment: Try this one: `SELECT t FROM T t WHERE t.id in (
 SELECT
  MAX(t.id)
 FROM T t
 outer join C c  on (c.id = t.c_id)
 WHERE
  t.m = :m AND
  t.c = c AND
  c.createdDate < :date
 GROUP BY t.m, t.p
)` I think you need check inner/outer join in this query and don't forget to pass fields fo joining.

Comment: @AleksandrsRudzitis -- switching to a `JOIN` does not improve performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is a special case of the common "top N per category" problem](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/09/22/how-to-write-efficient-top-n-queries-in-sql/), for which there are a few solutions in SQL. Why not just use native SQL? Your query could translate to:

```sql
SELECT (t).*
FROM (
  SELECT t, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.m_id, t.p_id ORDER BY t.id DESC) rn
  FROM t
  JOIN c ON t.c_id = c.id
  WHERE t.m_id = :m
  AND c.created_date < :date
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

The main difference is that you can avoid one access to the `T` table.

Of course, I'm assuming you have all the appropriate indexes, including indexes on all foreign keys and on the `C.CREATED_DATE` column. The result can still be mapped to an entity.

Note, [I'm using PostgreSQL specific syntax to nest records](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/05/14/selecting-all-columns-except-one-in-postgresql/), such that removing the `RN` column from the projection again is much easier.